# Python asynchronous function calls using aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to understand aiohttp a little better. Can someone check why my code is not printing the response of the request, instead it just prints the coroutine.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import requests

async def get_event_1(session):
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    headers = {
        'content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = await session.request('GET', url)
    return response.json()

async def get_event_2(session):
    url = "https://google.com"
    headers = {
        'content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = await session.request('GET', url)
    return response.json()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(
            get_event_1(session),
            get_event_2(session)
        )

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
x = loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
$ python async.py 
[<coroutine object ClientResponse.json at 0x10567ae60>, <coroutine object ClientResponse.json at 0x10567aef0>]
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientResponse.json' was never awaited
```

How do i print the responses instead?

Comment: You need to **await** `response.json()` as well: `return await response.json()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you received is informing you that a coroutine was never awaited.

You can see from the aiohttp documentation that `response.json()` is a also a coroutine and therefore must be awaited. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#json-response-content

```
return await response.json()
```